# ¿Como puedo hacer un formulario controlado en react dinamico?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Tengo un formulario

```
class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nombre: '',
            comensales: '',
            ingredientes: [],
            masIng: 0
        }
    }
    handleIngredientes = () => {
        let count = this.state.masIng
        this.setState({ masIng: count+1 })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Receta</p>
                <input type='text' name='nombre' placeholder='nombre' />
                <input type='number' name='comensales' placeholder='comensales' />
                <p>ingredientes <button className='btn' onClick={this.handleIngredientes}>Mas ingredientes</button></p>
                <App />
                {this.state.masIng > 0 ? <App /> : null}
                {this.state.masIng > 1 ? <App /> : null}
                {this.state.masIng > 2 ? <App /> : null}
                {this.state.masIng > 3 ? <App /> : null}
                {this.state.masIng > 4 ? <App /> : null}
                {this.state.masIng > 5 ? <App /> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

y un componente que es un input

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
            <input type='text' name='ingrediente' placeholder='ingrediente' />
            <input type='number' name='cantidad' placeholder='cantidad' />
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Mi duda es la siguiente: ¿cual es la forma correcta para que el usuario pueda darle al boton de mas ingredientes y se añadan inputs dinamicamente y pueda guardar correctamente el value y la cantidad de cada ingrediente en el estado de mi componente principal?

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar un bucle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes generar cada elemento en un bucle, con lo que no tienes que poner un if para cada línea (lo que limita innecesariamente el número de líneas)

```js
class Item extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);      
  }
  
  render() {
    return <p> Elemento {this.props.index} </p>;
  }

}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);      
  }
  
  generateRows(n) {
    let rows = [];
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
      rows.push(<Item index={i}/>);
    }
    return rows;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<div> {this.generateRows(this.props.amount)} </div>);
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App amount="3"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```